# qmake doesn't detect variables correctly

Tags: c++, qt, variables, definition, qmake

In this qmake code:

`MY_COMPILER = mingw

warning($$MY_COMPILER)
contains(MY_COMPILER, mingw)
{
    INCLUDEPATH += ../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0/src
    DEPENDPATH  += ../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0/src
    QMAKE_RPATHDIR *= ../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0/lib
    contains(QWT_CONFIG, QwtFramework) {

        LIBS      += -F../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0/lib
    }
    else {

        LIBS      += -L../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0/lib
    }

    IPATH       = ../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0/src
    warning(Using MinGW compiler)
}
else {
    INCLUDEPATH += ../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0-intel-shared/src
    DEPENDPATH  += ../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0-intel-shared/src
    QMAKE_RPATHDIR *= ../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0-intel-shared/lib
    contains(QWT_CONFIG, QwtFramework) {

        LIBS      += -F../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0-intel-shared/lib
    }
    else {

        LIBS      += -L../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0-intel-shared/lib
    }

    IPATH       = ../../libsrc/Qwt/qwt-6.0.1-win-Qt-4.8.0-intel-shared/src
    warning(Using Intel compiler)
}`

Whatever I define for the variable MY_COMPILER, it keeps taking the first condition, whilst it posts through the warning at line 3 the correct variable I entered.

How can I post a variable and then check whether it's defined?

Any efforts are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `contains($$MY_COMPILER, "mingw")` perhaps?

Comment: Didn't work :(, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I think the symbol $$ are to get at the value so it should be something basically like that. Usually I use different make files for different compilers as needed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but you could try it this way instead:

```
CONFIG += mingw

mingw {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

EDIT:

Another thing you could try is have the condition and opening curly bracket in the same line,
if I remember right, that caused some problems in the past.

Then the statement would look like this:

```
contains(MY_COMPILER, mingw) {
     //...
} else {
     //...
}
```

Comment: This conflicts with other stuff. I would not want to mess with CONFIG variables. When I used it, it gave me problems with resource files (I even tried changing variable name, but no use). It's really weird...!